# R create a subgroup sequential index based on sorted dataframe criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to make a subgroup index column in a sorted data.frame that increments the index based on when a condition occurs.  Consider the example from dput below which is a sf dataframe of points, grouped by the 'parent_group' column and sorted in time order within each group.  I then calculate the time difference and distance between sequential points within each parent group.

What I would like to do is add in a 'subgroup' column that increments a sequence based on when the time OR the distance for a given point is greater than some criteria (1000s or 1000m, for example) from the previous point within the parent group.

The subgroup column in the dataframe below is basically what I need to recreate,

In psuedo-code, something like:

```r
df.new <- df |> 
  group_by(parent_group) |>
  arrange(parent_group, dttm) |>

  # this is what I need to match the what I manually created in 'subgroup')
  mutate( = 
      if (is.na(dist)) {
         1  # start a new index at 1 for the parent_group when the first point in the sequence
      else if (dist > 1000 | delT > 1000)
         <increment the index>
      else
       
         <current index for the parent_group>  # as long as the next point in the sequence is in the same parent group and less than either the time/dist criteria, continue the index, 
         )
```

I assume there is some vectorized or efficient way of doing this rather than going row-by-row (and there could be millions of points.

```r
df <- structure(list(parent_group = c(366774330, 366774330, 366774330, 
366774330, 366774330, 366774330, 366774330, 366774330, 366774330, 
367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 
367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 
367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410, 367614410
), dttm = structure(c(1610966764, 1610966844, 1610966913, 1610966982, 
1613646483, 1613646554, 1613646618, 1613646683, 1613646744, 1610951131, 
1610951201, 1610951272, 1610951341, 1610977018, 1610977089, 1610977159, 
1610981520, 1610981589, 1610981658, 1610981730, 1610981799, 1613613278, 
1613613348, 1613613429, 1613613499, 1613613568, 1613613608), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), delT = structure(c(NA, 80, 69, 69, 2679501, 71, 64, 
65, 61, NA, 70, 71, 69, 25677, 71, 70, 4361, 69, 69, 72, 69, 
2631479, 70, 81, 70, 69, 40), units = "secs", class = "difftime"), 
    dist = structure(c(NA, 394.879903631431, 341.401084849659, 
    340.257524670908, 35382.2755194976, 410.003599585042, 332.042766019299, 
    337.141510972048, 334.749360094592, NA, 4.52020494721695, 
    6.06902133357221, 14.5300754789579, 10.1135187770607, 5.38213176277655, 
    4.18645836905046, 13.9336090976956, 1.39548594088128, 4.37135310329086, 
    5.19368248590136, 5.80244274451276, 27135.4202761378, 217.329926933193, 
    253.279683853908, 223.488271463273, 217.523956688808, 129.899239277968
    ), units = structure(list(numerator = "m", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
    subgroup = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), geometry = structure(list(
        structure(c(604609.690359738, 4482819.85101805), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(605002.432528286, 4482860.88426477
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(605341.825832819, 
        4482897.85568041), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(605680.415866786, 4482931.50047188), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(602620.948896233, 4518181.25341845
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(602564.151873532, 
        4517775.20286755), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(602382.38845673, 4517497.32796984), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(602063.278156752, 4517388.54830782
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(601729.516368849, 
        4517362.8538917), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574321.26253255, 
        4499347.1504607), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574320.372594717, 
        4499351.58219438), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(574315.332456118, 4499348.2013627), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574313.497133003, 4499362.61506044
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574321.173794428, 
        4499356.03082689), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(574325.368357132, 4499359.4032127), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574327.938340722, 4499356.09842556
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574314.375974351, 
        4499359.29337171), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(574313.519315302, 4499360.39496886), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574309.280385903, 4499361.46277292
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(574314.342700527, 
        4499362.62350907), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(574312.707020578, 4499357.05638298), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(600415.618592362, 4491942.94544247
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(600208.225443215, 
        4491877.98099967), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(599967.133682482, 4491800.35779979), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(599754.713529176, 4491730.89784045
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(599546.433101649, 
        4491668.16080799), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(599423.378808378, 4491626.55007292), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 574309.280385903, 
    ymin = 4482819.85101805, xmax = 605680.415866786, ymax = 4518181.25341845
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:32618", 
        wkt = "PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n            MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 18N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-75,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Between 78°W and 72°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Bahamas. Canada - Nunavut; Ontario; Quebec. Colombia. Cuba. Ecuador. Greenland. Haiti. Jamica. Panama. Turks and Caicos Islands. United States (USA). Venezuela.\"],\n        BBOX[0,-78,84,-72]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",32618]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), class = c("sf", 
"grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), groups = structure(list(parent_group = c(366774330, 367614410
), .rows = structure(list(1:9, 10:27), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(parent_group = NA_integer_, 
dttm = NA_integer_, delT = NA_integer_, dist = NA_integer_, subgroup = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have some kind of group that you want to put things into based on a logic check, the best way to do it is using `cumsum()`.

In the code below, we check if either of the columns are NAs, replacing the values with 0 if necessary, then checking if either are true, then finding the cumulative sum of that column (it is already grouped by parent_group, otherwise I would do this. I would also keep the dataframe in an `ungroup()`'d state, but you do you.

```
df |> mutate(subgroup = cumsum(as.integer(ifelse(is.na(dist), 0, dist)) > dist_threshold | ifelse(is.na(delT), 0, delT) > time_threshold))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!  So did Andre's answer, but I marked this one has answer as it was first but also it performed *marginally* faster (~2 milliseconds) than Andre's answer on a ~250k dataset.

Answer (score 1):

First getting the condition, then filling `NA`s, finally generating the sequence.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(subgroup_new = delT > 1000 | dist > 1000, .by = parent_group) %>% 
  fill(subgroup_new, .direction="updown") %>% 
  mutate(subgroup_new = consecutive_id(cumsum(subgroup_new)), .by = parent_group)
```

Comment: as op said, the dataframe is already grouped, so .by = parent_group is unnecessary :-)

Comment: Thanks Andre, this worked almost equally well, however I actually find your answer a bit easier to understand (and learned some new helpful tidyverse functions!), however Mark's solution was marginally faster (and first)

Comment: @DarwinsBeard No worries, glad it helped, in whatever way. Not so sure about the "first" though :)

Comment: @Mark I tend to post complete approaches to avoid ambiguities, and grouping is important here, so I decided to include it, even if it risks being redundant :)